# Send data to another web component

Tags: javascript, html, web-component, shadow-dom, custom-element

I am trying out web component recently and I came across a problem, how do I send data from the first component to the second component?

I tried to use event but the second component can't receive the data, this is what I did:
(I am totally new to this, not sure if I am doing the right way)

**Index.html**

```
<body>
  <first-component>
    <p>First component!</p>
  </first-component>

  <second-component>
    <p>Second component!</p>
  </second-component>

    <script src="./component-one.js"></script>
    <script src="./component-two.js"></script>
</body>
```

**component-one.js**

```
const firstComponentTemplate = document.createElement('template');
firstComponentTemplate.id = 'first-component-template';
firstComponentTemplate.innerHTML = `
<div id="first-component-container">
  <slot></slot>
  <button>Click</button>
</div>
`;

class FirstComponent extends HTMLElement {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});
    this.shadowRoot.appendChild(firstComponentTemplate.content.cloneNode(true));
  }

  btnClick() {
    const btnHtml = this.shadowRoot.querySelector('button');
    btnHtml.addEventListener('click', () => {
      this.dispatchEvent(
        new CustomEvent('a-custom-event', {
          bubbles: true,
          composed: true,
          detail: {
            value: 'Some value',
          },
        })
      );
    });
  }

  connectedCallback() {
    this.btnClick();
  }
}

customElements.define('first-component', FirstComponent);
```

**component-two.js**

```
const secondComponentTemplate = document.createElement('template');
secondComponentTemplate.id = 'second-component-template';
secondComponentTemplate.innerHTML = `
<div id="second-component-container">
  <slot></slot>
</div>
`;

class SecondComponent extends HTMLElement {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});
    this.shadowRoot.appendChild(secondComponentTemplate.content.cloneNode(true));
  }

  connectedCallback() {
    this.shadowRoot.addEventListener('a-custom-event', function (event) {
      console.log(event); //Check console but nothing in console
    });
  }
}

customElements.define('second-component', SecondComponent);
```

So as you can see, I am trying to pass the data from first custom element to second custom element,
 
**how come this is not working, which part am I doing wrong?

is this the correct way to do it?

is it bad practice to pass/receive data from one component to another sibling component?**

Thanks

Comment: Put the listener on a common (parent) DOM element. If you attach it ``.this.shadowRoot`` it will only listen "to itself" It is like you shouting in your house and your neighbor does not hear you. You have to shout at a location where your neighbor hears you... either IN HIS house or out in the street

Comment: Hi, is there an other way to send the data to other sibling components? other than using the custom event

Comment: Calling methods directly or Events, that is it. One is Tell the other is Listen. Events come in many forms, standard Events (click), Custom Events, Server Sent Events (SSE)